# HTTP Status 404 - /sdnext/save.html, The requested resource (/sdnext/save.html) is not available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, web

This is a controller class for my web application.
@Controller
public class BookController {

```
@Autowired
private BookService bookService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command") BooksBean bookBean, 
        BindingResult result) {
    Book book = prepareModel(bookBean);
    bookService.addBook(book);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/add.html");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listBooks() {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("books",  prepareListofBean(bookService.listBooks()));
    return new ModelAndView("booksList", model);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addBook(@ModelAttribute("command") BooksBean booksBean,
        BindingResult result) {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("books",  prepareListofBean(bookService.listBooks()));
    return new ModelAndView("addBook", model);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView welcome() {
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editBook(@ModelAttribute("command")  BooksBean booksBean,
        BindingResult result) {
    bookService.deleteBook(prepareModel(booksBean));
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("book", null);
    model.put("books",  prepareListofBean(bookService.listBooks()));
    return new ModelAndView("addBook", model);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteBook(@ModelAttribute("command") BooksBean booksBean,
        BindingResult result) {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("book", prepareBooksBean(bookService.getBook(booksBean.getBookCode())));
    model.put("books",  prepareListofBean(bookService.listBooks()));
    return new ModelAndView("addBook", model);
}

private Book prepareModel(BooksBean booksBean){
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setBookName(booksBean.getBookName());
    book.setBookCode(booksBean.getBookCode());
    book.setAuthor(booksBean.getAuthor());
    book.setDateOfArrival(booksBean.getDateOfArrival());
    book.setPrice(booksBean.getPrice());
    book.setRackId(booksBean.getRackId());
    book.setNumberOfBooks(booksBean.getNumberOfBooks());
    book.setSubjectCode(booksBean.getSubjectCode());
    return book;
}

private List<BooksBean> prepareListofBean(List<Book> books){
    List<BooksBean> beans = null;
    if(books != null && !books.isEmpty())
    {
        beans = new ArrayList<BooksBean>();
        BooksBean bean = null;
        for(Book book : books){
            bean = new BooksBean();
            bean.setBookName(book.getBookName());
            bean.setBookCode(book.getBookCode());
            bean.setAuthor(book.getAuthor());
            bean.setDateOfArrival(book.getDateOfArrival());
            bean.setPrice(book.getPrice());
            bean.setRackId(book.getRackId());
            bean.setNumberOfBooks(book.getNumberOfBooks());
            bean.setSubjectCode(book.getSubjectCode());
            beans.add(bean);
        }
    }
    return beans;
}

private BooksBean prepareBooksBean(Book book){
    BooksBean bean = new BooksBean();
    bean.setBookName(book.getBookName());
    bean.setBookCode(book.getBookCode());
    bean.setAuthor(book.getAuthor());
    bean.setDateOfArrival(book.getDateOfArrival());
    bean.setPrice(book.getPrice());
    bean.setRackId(book.getRackId());
    bean.setNumberOfBooks(book.getNumberOfBooks());
    bean.setSubjectCode(book.getSubjectCode());
    return bean;
}
```

}

This is page for adding element in spring.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Add Employee Data</h2>
        <form:form method="POST" action="/sdnext/save.html">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="bookName">Name Of Book:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="bookName" value="${book.bookName}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="bookCode">Book Code:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="bookCode" value="${book.bookCode}" readonly="true"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="author">Book Author Name:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="author" value="${book.author}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="dateOfArrival">Date Of Arrival:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="dateOfArrival" value="${book.dateOfArrival}"/></td>
                </tr>
```

this is a web.xml file which contains mapping.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

this sdnext-servlet.xml file which is used for defining context path and jsp resolver and datbase handler.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tcs" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.tcs.model.Book</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Where is the question? Could you please tell us about the problem? What is it? How did you get it?

Comment: I think there is problem in mapping. I shared the servlet.xml and web.xml